# Ruby Gem Twitter - Twitter::Error::ClientError: initialize: name or service not known

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, rubygems, client

I want to use the ruby gem 'twitter' but for an unknown reason it does not work.
Here's the error I get when running the script:

`C:/nwcloud/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/faraday-0.8.6/lib/faraday/reques/multipart.rb:5 warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_BOUNDARY
Twitter::Error::ClientError: initialize: name or service not known
                         request at C:/nwcloud/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/twitter-4.5.0/lib/twitter/client.rb:85
                             get at C:/nwcloud/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/twitter-4.5.0/lib/twitter/client.rb:64
                        __send__ at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1671
                            send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2094
            cursor_from_response at C:/nwcloud/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/twitter-4.5.0/lib/twitter/api/utils.rb:108
  cursor_from_response_with_user at C:/nwcloud/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/twitter-4.5.0/lib/twitter/api/utils.rb:96
                         friends at C:/nwcloud/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/twitter-4.5.0/lib/twitter/api/friends_and_followers.rb:314
                          (root) at tCon.rb:11`

I registered my application in my twitter developer account and installed the gem.
Here's my coding (I removed all keys):

> require 'twitter'
>
> client = Twitter::Client.new(
>
> :consumer_key => "",
>
> :consumer_secret => "",
>
> :oauth_token => "",
>
> :oauth_token_secret => ""
>
> )
>
> client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")`

I also tried just to do it like this:

> Twitter.configure do |config|
>
> config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
>
> config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
>
> config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
>
> config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
>
> end

.. it doesn't work :-( .. I'm a newbie to ruby so perhaps I forgot sth... 
I'm really looking forward to your answers. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a proxy problem. After deploying it to the cloud it worked!